# Pallets extrinsics not showing in a relay-chain/parachain setup

Tags: parachain, relay-chain, parachain-collator

I followed the steps in [this cumulus tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay/), all is running fine and smooth, but I can't find the `template-pallet` or any other pallet I try to add in the parachain.

- Is it normal ?

I've [read that](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/connect-parachain/):

> You cannot, at this time, connect a parachain with any previous state to a relay chain.

- So maybe I have to live-upgrade the parachain to include the new pallets ?
- What are the steps to include custom logic in a parachain ?

Comment: Are you sure you have pointed the polkadot-js ui at the parachain port rather than the relay chain? 8844 would be the port if you're following this guide: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/connect-parachain/

Comment: OMG yes indeed I was using the embedded relay chain node ws port ! Not the collator ws port,thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was answered by Squirrel - they weren't showing up because Polkadot-JS was pointing at the relay chain, not the parachain.